# Does android SIP library support SSL/TLS?

Tags: android, sip

I am trying to

```
ENABLE_TLS = true
and TLS_VERIFY_SERVER = true
```

but I am getting

> SSL certificate verification error

.
Any help?

Comment: ivalid certificate? missing CA certificate?